# Restoring icons in finder toolbar

Tags: macos, finder, icon

Yesterday, for no reason I can think of, the toolbar icons in osx finder disappeared (1st image).  Icons for files are unaffected (2nd image).

How can the finder toolbar icons be restored?

I tried commands in terminal for clearing icon services cache ([source](http://furbo.org/2015/01/19/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-yosemite/)), but that did not affect anything.  I also read several articles on apple.stackexchange and others found via web search, but found nothing that quite hit this problem.

[image]

[image: File Icons Are OK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the Toolbar.

Select Icon Only or Icon & Text.

[image]